# Run HTML codes in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

What if a JSON file has HTML in it.
How do we run HTML in flutter apps?

like if there is h4 tag, that should be a little bigger than regular text and so so.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

get the html value from the json and render it on the app using this package:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html